# JaCoCo 0.8.4 - Error: Could not find or load main class –javaagent:jacocoagent.jar

Tags: java, command-line, jacoco, javaagents

I would like to use JaCoCo in command line so I tried :

```
java –javaagent:jacocoagent.jar -jar task_evaluation.jar
```

in my project structure :

```
   task_evaluation.jar
   jacocoagent.jar
```

But I get this error message :

```
Could not find or load main class –javaagent:jacocoagent.jar
```

My Jar is correctly build ( it works as expected without the javaagent ) so the error doesn't come from here.

[image]

My MANIFEST.MF :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . /libs/junit-4.12.jar /libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
Created-By: 1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: src.StudentTestRunner
```

I donwload the jar file from https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/index.html (and copied the lib/jacocoagent.jar , lib/jacococli.jar )

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are missed obligatory option `=destfile=jacoco.exec`. Try: `java –javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec -jar task_evaluation.jar`

Comment: I thought there was some default values : https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html . Same error :(

Comment: Your are right. I was reading "wrong page" [https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html)

Comment: No problem : other idea ? Like something in my manifest ( I will add it to the question )

Comment: Make sure `java -jar task_evaluation.jar` works. have you tried setup correctly your JACOCO path?

Comment: java -jar task_evaluation.jar works ; the jacoco lib in the same folder that task_evaluation.jar ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196187/discussion-between-valijon-and-jy95).

Comment: Seems some problems with MANIFEST.MF Try to compile jar file from IDE (not manually) and check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the command itself - we must use <kbd>-</kbd>, not <kbd>–</kbd>

```
java -javaagent:jacocoagent.jar -jar task_evaluation.jar
```